# Eclipse Android - Debugger doesn't stop at breakpoint on OnClick method

Tags: android, debugging, breakpoints

I want to debug my `onClick` method in my `SaveActivity`:

```
public class SaveActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_save);

    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

// For the Back Button
// (http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        // This is called when the Home (Up) button is pressed
        // in the Action Bar.
        Intent parentActivityIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        parentActivityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(parentActivityIntent);
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onClick(View view) {

    switch (view.getId()) {   // <-- On this line is my Breakpoint
    case R.id.location_save:

        EditText formName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.location_name);
        String locationName = formName.getText().toString();
        EditText formDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.location_desc);
        String locationDesc = formDesc.getText().toString();
        // Example for New York
        String locationLatitude = "40.714353";
        String locationLongitude = "-74.005973";

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        Location newLocation = new Location(locationName, locationDesc,
                locationLatitude, locationLongitude);
        db.addLocation(newLocation);
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(SaveActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("id", newLocation.getId()); 
        SaveActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);

    }
}
```

}

Now i added a Breakpoint on the `switch`-Statemant in the onClick method. Then i click on this Button in my `activity_save.xml`:

```
<Button
   android:id="@+id/location_save"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/location_save" >
</Button>
```

So it should stop at my breakpoint, but nothing happend.
What did i wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this in your button layout to bind the method to its onClick:

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

Comment: Either this or call setOnClickListener on the view and pass it an onClickListener.  Without one of these methods, it won't know to hook up the onClickListener to your onClick function-  android uses objects for this, it doesn't do automatic hookups